# slick grid header row cell alignment

Tags: javascript, css, slickgrid

I'm using a slick grid to display data in grid. Slick grid calculates all the stuff like height, width when that particular grid is created and the grid looks really fine. 
The trouble foments when the grid is created but is hidden and on action of something else (checkbox/radio button select) the grid becomes visible. this time the calculation goes awry and the headers and row cells (column for the header) are not aligned vertically..
[image]

I m unable to understand how to control this. If anyone else too has suffered at the hands of the slick grid and have been able to defend themselves please bare the ammunitions.

In anticipation,
Premanshu

Answer (score 13):

None of these solutions worked for me, may be because SlickGrid's code changed since 2012 :)
I found a solution in this [post](http://technotes.zettlemoyer.com/post/53785064701/get-slickgrid-to-render-properly-when-box-sizing-is-set), it's similar to @Wex's, but with tiny differences:

```
.slickgrid, 
.slickgrid *,
.slick-header-column {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Where `.slickgrid` is a selector of a grid container element.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to get this to work in bootstrap 3 (an environment where `box-sizing` is set to `border-box`) just by applying `box-sizing: content-box` to the `.slick-header-column`.

```css
.slick-header > .slick-header-columns > .slick-header-column {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;                                                              
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box; }
```

---

Just be careful when modifying the `border` properties of `.slick-header-column`. I was able to remove the border on the right by setting the color to `transparent`:

```css
.slick-header > .slick-header-columns > .slick-header-column:last-child { 
  border-right-color: transparent;
}
```

***Note***: You can play around with the selector specificity - the selector you're overwriting is:

```css
.slick-header-column.ui-state-default { ... }
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem when using it on a page that had twitter bootstrap css on it. The solution was to override the box-sizing to content-box

*, *:before, *:after {
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
box-sizing: content-box;
}

probably should figure out exactly which classes really need it, but that sorted things for me.

Comment: Best just to override the subelements of .grid, otherwise you can impact Bootstrap, which expects to deal with border-box sizes. E.g. `.grid *, .grid:before *, .grid:after * { 
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; 
 -moz-box-sizing: content-box; 
 box-sizing: content-box; 
}`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when dynamically displaying/hiding grids using JQuery `.show()` and `.hide()`.

If you create the `div` tag with `display: none` (so it is initially hidden) the grid columns do not initialise properly. To workaround this I create the div tag with `visibility: hidden` and remove this style before using the `.hide()`and `.show()` methods.

My code looks roughly like this:

```
  <div id="mygrid" style="visibility: hidden"></div>

  $grid = $("#mygrid")

  grid = new Slick.Grid($grid, gridData, gridColumns, gridOptions);

  // Hide grid by default, remembering to remove the visibility style
  $grid.hide();
  $grid.css("visibility", "visible");

  // You can now show and hide the grid using normal jQuery methods
  $grid.show();
  $grid.hide();
```

Once it is initialised and the `visibility: hidden;` property is removed, I'm using `.hide()`and `.show()` but I suspect this will work if you manipulate the `display: none;` attribute directly if you're not using JQuery.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @njr..Thanks for the reply...but somehow this workaround doesn't seem considerate enough to solve the issue.
![Image in the question](C:\Users\premanshu\Desktop\slick alignment1
is what I'm getting after utilising your reply.

Comment: I have also added some custom classes to the headers and it seems that this is the reason behind this mis alignment. I tried one in jsfiddle using yours and it was working fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/wLPLA/13/

Comment: In your jsFiddle you have the grid defined with `display:none` in the HTML markup. Try using `visibility: hidden` instead

Comment: the updated fiddle is 
http://jsfiddle.net/wLPLA/18/
but it gives me the same result

Comment: Which browser. Tested in FF and Chrome and both look fine. Maybe you can include a screenshot.

Comment: The problem that is plaguing me is yet to be identified. While things are rosier in jsfiddle, they turn _offenders_ while running in any of the browsers. @njr: Is it possible due to the fact that if I've appended some classes to the headers and they are the culprits !!!!

Comment: Yes, using custom classes could well be related, especially if you have edited the standard style sheets. The answer I suggested is based only on the solution that solved my problem. My suggestion would be to start with the standard and add your classes in one by one until it breaks. If @Tin says that this should work then I believe him - he wrote the thing after all.

Comment: @Tin: Would u please share if SlickGrid is supposed to be compatible with IE7?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and after reading the answers from @Premanshu and @Tin I found a different route to solve it.

Basically you need to skip an event cycle and let the DOM catch up before you display the grid this will allow it to find the right column widths. I used setTimeout to do it.

```
    var myGrid = $("<div id='myGrid' style='width:600px;height:500px;'></div>");
    grid = new Slick.Grid(myGrid, data, columns, options);


   // ... later on, append the container to the DOM and initialize SlickGrid
   setTimeout(function(){
     myGrid.appendTo(that.$el);
     grid.init();
   },1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is supported and shouldn't happen.  In fact, most of the examples (including http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example1-simple.html) have that same implementation just to make sure it works correctly.

Can you include a jsfiddle.net repro?

Comment: if the grid is initialised and visible on page load, it works perfectly alright. But if the grid is initialised and not visible on page load it doesn't work the good way.

Comment: Was this supported in the release 1.4.2???
I'm using that release as the baseline and on top of it exists my customisations.

Comment: I don't recall when it was changed.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it for me. 
This is what i was doing : 
1. Initialise grid
2. append data to it
3. Present it using modal of div containing grid

To Resolve i did this : 
1. Present it using modal of div containing grid
2. Initialise grid
3. Append data